# how i can make a mongodb query (or find()) with a variable using python?

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb, find

I need tranfer data from a database in `MySQL to MongoDB`.
I have a Mysql's query with a few data:

```
SELECT data FROM table where data BETWEEN r1 AND r2
```

that i storaged in a list

so my problem is
when i try to find the data in mongodb (the data was in) i made this:
`datamongo = collection.find({"data" : data[x]})`
and the result is nothing, literaly.

I need to create a loop with the list range and search every data in the list in mongodb.
I tried with `find() and find_one()` but no one of them works.
BUT all works if i put a constant instead of a variable.

I hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the `regex` part. You need to use that value in a way as explained below

```
collection.find({"data" : new RegExp(data[x], 'i')})
```

Or you can also use

```
collection.find( { 'data' : { '$regex' : data[x], '$options' : 'i' } } )
```

Note that `i` in `RegExp`, this is just for case insensitive comparison. Remove it if you want strict comparison.

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. thanks for answer.
I try with that but i still have the problem.

code:
datasql = cursor.fetchall()
query = str(datasql[0])

datamongo = collection.find_one({
"datetime" : {"$regex" : query, "$options" : "i"},
"zone" : "MX"
},
{"datetime" : 1} 
)

data = str(datamongo)
print(data)
and the console print "none"

Comment: this is because it's asynchronous.